# Google Hangouts in Windows Application (.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, google-hangouts

I am creating a Windows Application on .Net Platform with C#.
How can I use *Google Hangouts* in this Application?

Comment: Which windows applicaiton? winforms? wpf?

Comment: Winforms Application.

Comment: You at the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a website where some else had the same Question

[Link to the Site](http://forums.asp.net/t/2020079.aspx?How%20to%20integrate%20google%20hangout%20api%20in%20asp%20net%20c%20)

And the Hangouts Getting Started API Guide.

Hangouts - Getting Started: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started

Comment: Thanks I am trying now.